# Creating .csv file from an Access table using C#

Tags: c#, csv, ms-access-2003

I am trying to write a program which creates a .csv file from an Access table. I'm not sure how to do this and everything I've found while researching this is how to do the opposite, creating an Access table from a .csv file.

So far, I have created a windows forms application that allows the user to select a data path to the access directory (.mdb) and then after pushing the "Go" button, a list of the tables in the directory is shown in a listbox.

What I need to do next, which I have no idea how to, is allow the user to select one of the tables, which would then create a .csv file from the selected table. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace TranslatorHelper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void btnPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dialogText = "";
        // Show the dialog and get result.
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            dialogText = openFileDialog1.ToString();
            dialogText = dialogText.Replace("System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog: Title: , FileName: ", "");
            txtDataPath.Text = dialogText;
        }
    }

    private void btnGetTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Microsoft Access provider factory
        DbProviderFactory factory =
        DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

        DataTable userTables = null;

        using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+txtDataPath.Text;

            // We only want user tables, not system tables
            string[] restrictions = new string[4];
            restrictions[3] = "Table";

            connection.Open();

            // Get list of user tables
            userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
        }

    // Add list of table names to listBox
    for (int i = 0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
    lstTables.Items.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());

    }

    private void lstTables_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Please offer any advice you can, anything is appreciated, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I can shove you in the proper direction:

You have the start, which is the DbConnection.  You can then create a DbCommand from that:

```
DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
```

From there, you can assign text, such as:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;  //you might have to wrap the table name with quotes or square brackets!
```

Then you can get a reader:

```
DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
```

Once you have the reader, you've got the data, meaning you can then:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyNewTable");
dt.Load(reader);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in row.Columns)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
            sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(row[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
}
```

To get the ListBox selection, you could use:

```
lstTables.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

That should give you the item, or in your case a table name.  Don't forget that certain words are reserved in SQL (and it also depends on which SQL it is), so you might have to be careful using the table name directly in the SQL string for the CommandText parameter.

Also, I would see no need to use a SelectedIndexChanged event handler unless you need to do something immediately upon the user making a selection.  If the behavior you want from the user is to make a selection and then click a button to start a process, then it's unnecessary to handle the change.

Comment: He would then need to iterate through the data reader and output the csv there or use it to build something else to store/save the data.

Comment: @Justin That's right.  Figured if that's not enough, I can expand on it.  But once you have the data, it should be much simpler.  Then you just loop the records and StringBuilder your way to fame!

Comment: For the actual creating of the CSV file I have seen a few other posts here recommending [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/), a free and open source .NET library for import/export to text files.

Comment: Added a bit more, just in case.

Comment: How do I know which table was selected from my listbox while still inside the button method?

Comment: What if `row[dc.ColumnName].ToString()` contains a comma?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, you'd have to handle that possibility.  And if you decide to quote the string, you then must handle the possibility that it also contains a quote of some kind.

Comment: @user2390773 I've added some example code for the listbox issue.

Comment: oh ok, I was thinking I had to wait for the selected item from the listbox but I'll just be using a separate button to export the table to csv